# Trouble grouping by date when counting rows in R

Tags: r, date, dataframe, dplyr, grouping

I am using a public dataset of Donald Trump tweets, which can be found here:
https://www.kaggle.com/kingburrito666/better-donald-trump-tweets

After doing so I am trying to group it by date in R. Firstly, I would like to count the number of tweets pr. day and secondly I would like to Summarise the "Favourites" and "Retweets" pr. day.

I have written the following code, but it gives me errors all the time... Can you help me?

Thanks in advance!

```
 Donald <- read_csv(file="Donald-Tweets!.csv")
Donald
#Grouped
G_filter <- Donald %>%
  select(Date,twt_favourites_IS_THIS_LIKE_QUESTION_MARK, Retweets) %>% 
  rename( Favourites = twt_favourites_IS_THIS_LIKE_QUESTION_MARK) %>% 
  group_by(as.Date.date(Date)) %>% 
summarise(Total = sum(Favourites+Retweets), count(n))


View(G_filter)
```

Comment: What is `as.Date.date`?

Comment: Also, some sample data might help, which would let us see whether that call to `as.Date()` would even make sense.

Comment: "... but it gives me errors all the time ..." you should be explicit about the error message. Error messages often provide constructive feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is probably what you are looking for.

```
library(tidyverse)

G_filter <- Donald %>%
  select(Date, twt_favourites_IS_THIS_LIKE_QUESTION_MARK, Retweets) %>% 
  rename(Favourites = twt_favourites_IS_THIS_LIKE_QUESTION_MARK) %>% 
  group_by(Date) %>%
  mutate(Favorites_and_Retweets = Favourites + Retweets) %>%
  summarise(Favorites_and_Retweets = sum(Favorites_and_Retweets),
            Count = n())
G_filter
# # A tibble: 479 x 3
#    Date     Favorites_and_Retweets Count
#    <chr>                     <int> <int>
#  1 15-07-16                  66899    39
#  2 15-07-17                  65212    22
#  3 15-07-18                  97381    32
#  4 15-07-19                  34229    12
#  5 15-07-20                  62316    37
#  6 15-07-21                  88132    62
#  7 15-07-22                  69919    37
#  8 15-07-23                  67963    43
#  9 15-07-24                  67687    35
# 10 15-07-25                  39744    25
# # ... with 469 more rows
```

There is no need to convert the `Date` column. If you really want to do that, one way is to load the `lubridate` package, and then do `mutate(Date = ymd(Date))` in the pipeline.